# How would I search a text file for a specific name, and print the whole line with Python?

Tags: python, text-files

My code is currently:

```
def GrabCPUInfo():
    with open("cpu_list.txt", "r") as file:
        line = file.readlines()
        if cpu in line:
            print(line)
        else:
            print("Incorrect information")
```

My issue is that it just keeps printing out "Incorrect information" instead of printing out the whole line that includes the cpu name.

Comment: What's the value of `cpu`?

Comment: Like this it will check if a line is exactly the value of `cpu`. No extra characters allowed. Maybe you want to iterate over the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines()` returns a list of strings where each element of the list is an entire line in the text file. For example, using `readlines` on this text file...

```
bob
joe
emily
```

would create the list `['bob\n', 'joe\n', 'emily\n']`

Unless `cpu` matches an entire line exactly (including the newline character), using `in` like this won't work. You can still use `in` on the individual strings to test if the string contains `cpu`. Try something like this:

```py
def GrabCPUInfo():
    with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if cpu in line:
```

I removed the `else` block because it would just print "Incorrect information" over and over again for every line that didn't have the correct string.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have a file `cpu_list.txt` with the value

```
CPU 1: Example
CPU 2: Example
CPU 3: Example
```

You could do something like

```py
with open('cpu_list.txt','r') as f:
    # Read content as well removing \n
    content = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    # print(content)
    # ['CPU 1: Example', 'CPU 2: Example', 'CPU 3: Example']
    for line in content:
        if 'CPU 1' in line:
            print(line)
        else:
            print('Invalid Info')
        break
```

The output

```
CPU 1: Example
```